# Compare local node module version with package.json version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I want to ask this question is because I met some problems when I co-work with other developers.

Sometimes, other developers update node modules version, and I pull the new commit and forgot to install new modules.

It would cause some problems when run the code. And I didn't realize the bug was caused by update module version at first. It took me some time to debug in wrong way.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Like compare your local node_module with your package.json setting.

I think of one way is to create a git plugin. This plugin will notify you when package.json changed.

I also try to find some modules but what these modules do is to compare local version to npm registry version. (like [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates))

Is there anyway to compare local node_module with package.json setting?

I think it will also help when deploy the code to production mode.(to do the pre-publish check)

Answer (score -1):

2 things: 
If want to be notified when the package.json has been updated, I think the standard `git pull` command should be enough as it displays all the file updated by you co-workers commits.

If you want to avoid launching your dev environment with some missing dependencies, I think the best way is to add a grunt (gulp,or any other task runner) `install-dependencies` task that will be required for your `grunt serve` command.

Doing so, you'll never miss a package.json update, and this will force you to maintain all your local dependencies up-to-date and homogeneous with your team.

hope this help

Comment: Sure, exam package.json is one method. But as you know, in some case we may miss to update. So that's why I think maybe that have solution to bind the node module version validation before some important action ( like deploy to production).

Comment: What you are saying: 
1_ You think that in some cases, your co-workers have pushed bad code (a nodejs version updated) and then, what you need is more like a continuous integration and testing system before going in production.
2_ The code pushed is OK, but you forgot to install all the dependencies: then I recommend using a process manager that will handle the automatic dependencies deployment (something StrongLoop for instance should do ? Sorry, I used to do it manually